# Eclipse deployment assembly - How to remove multiple jar files?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, deployment

I am super frustrated by that... Sometimes when you change repository locations there are some jar files left on the deployment assembly path that are not referenced any more or couldn't be found. You can only remove these one by one... Is there any workaround to remove multiple files in this case?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a UI glitch. If you hold ctrl or cmd and click multiple jars and then click remove all the selected ones will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may actually begin prior to removing the jar files.  When adding libraries to your deployment assembly try adding the parent folder instead of the individual jar files.